# How to create internal blocking queue in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

Is there any way to create internal blocking queue and produce messages(multiple workers? to the queue and consume(multiple workers) from the queue? or any other way to implement this behaviour? I am not able to find relevant example in ballerina site?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/ballerina-guides/messaging-with-kafka

Comment: Not really, I am looking something like this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html. Not really looking for external queuing products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM, Ballerina doesn't have a Blocking Queue implementation OOTB. However, it seems you can use [Ballerina Streams](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/streams.html) to cater to your requirement. If that's not what you are looking for, then you might have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, is streaming API thread/concurrency safe to use by multiple workers?